# How can I improve this LaTeX code?

Tags: symbols, phonetic

I have a document with English phrases. The stressed words are bold and have a larger dot above them. The unstressed words have a smaller dot above them.

[image]

I like the current layout. This is the LaTeX code I'm using:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setmainfont{Charis SIL}

\geometry{a4paper, left=1in, right=1in, top=0.5in, bottom=0.65in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.4}

\usepackage{tikz}         

\usepackage{stackengine}
\renewcommand\stacktype{L}

\newcommand{\lstress}[1]
{%
    \addstackgap[10pt]{\stackon{#1}{%
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \fill[opacity=0] circle (0.5ex);
                \fill circle (0.25ex);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }%
    }%
}%

\newcommand{\hstress}[1]
{%
    \addstackgap[10pt]{\stackon{\bfseries{#1}}{\tikz \fill circle (0.5ex);}}%
}%

\begin{document}
    
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    
    \begin{enumerate}   
        \item \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word}
        
        \par\addvspace{-0.5ex}{phonetic transcription phonetic transcription phonetic transcription phonetic transcription phonetic transcription phonetic transcription}\par\addvspace{3ex}
        
        \item \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word}
        
        \par\addvspace{-0.5ex}{phonetic transcription phonetic transcription phonetic transcription phonetic transcription phonetic transcription phonetic transcription}\par\addvspace{3ex}
        
        \item \hstress{What} \hstress{kind} \lstress{of} \hstress{books} \lstress{do} \lstress{you} \hstress{like} \lstress{to} \hstress{read}?
        \par\addvspace{-0.5ex}{phonetic transcription}\par\addvspace{3ex}
    \end{enumerate}

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\end{document}
```

The first phrase is longer and wraps on two lines.

Notice that I repeat `\par\addvspace{-0.5ex}` and `\par\addvspace{3ex}` for each paragraph in the phonetic transcription. Is it possible to create a macro with `newcommand` which does that automatically? maybe by wrapping the phrase into something like `\phrase{.....}` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, your LaTeX code should be improved like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\def\baselinestretch {1.4}

\def\lstress#1{\leavevmode\vbox{\halign{\hfil##\hfil\cr\cr$\ssize\bullet$\cr#1\cr}}}
\def\hstress#1{\leavevmode\vbox{\halign{\hfil##\hfil\cr\cr$\bullet$\cr\bf#1\cr}}}
\let\ssize=\scriptscriptstyle

\def\replspace #1 #2{\space #1-%
   \ifx#2\end \else \expandafter\replspace\expandafter#2\fi}
\def\metrix #1#2{\leavevmode \def\tmpa{#1}%
   \edef\tmpb{\replspace #2 \end}\expandafter\meA\tmpb\end}
\def\meA #1#2-{\meB{#1#2}\isnextchar{ }{ \meA}{\isnextchar\end{\meE}{\meA}}}
\def\meB#1{\expandafter\nextA\tmpa\relax\end
   \ifx\next*\hstress{#1}\fi
   \ifx\next.\lstress{#1}\fi
}
\def\nextA #1#2\end{\let\next=#1\def\tmpa{#2}}
\def\meE{\let\next=}

\def\isnextchar#1#2#3{\begingroup\toks0={\endgroup#2}\toks1={\endgroup#3}%
   \let\tmp= #1\futurelet\next\isnextcharA
}
\def\isnextcharA{\the\toks\ifx\tmp\next0\else1\fi\space}

\def\phrase#1#2#3#4{\metrix{#1}{#2}#3\vskip-0.5ex\relax #4\vskip3ex\relax}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

\begin{enumerate}   
    \item \phrase
    { .    *    .    *    .    *    .    *    .    *    .    *    .    *    .    *    .    *    .    *  }
    {Word Word Word Word Word Word Word Word Word Word Word Word Word Word Word Word Word Word Word Word}.
    {phonetic transcription phonetic transcription phonetic transcription phonetic transcription phonetic transcription phonetic transcription}

    \item \phrase
    { .    *    .    *    .    *    .    *    .    *  }
    {Word Word Word Word Word Word Word Word Word Word}.
    {phonetic transcription phonetic transcription phonetic transcription phonetic transcription phonetic transcription phonetic transcription}

    \item \phrase
    { *    *   .   *     .  .   *    .  *  }
    {What kind of books do you like to read}?
    {phonetic transcription}

    \item \phrase
    {.   *     .    *    .  }
    {A-longer-word Word Word}.
    {}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Note, I didn't use any LaTeX package. Maybe, if you need to use `Charis SIL` (I don't have this font) then use `fontspec` of course.

Comment: Thank you. Stress is on syllables, not words. Certain words have two syllables stressed (primary and secondary stress). In my example everything stressed is represented with the star (large dots) and everything unstressed with small dots. I don't make difference between the primary and secondary stress with separate symbolls but I need certain words to have two or three marks above it. Your example only accept one dot or star above a word.

Comment: Here's an example: https://ibb.co/7g8cz1f

Comment: BTW, I like your example because it makes the content between `begin{document}` and `end{document}` more readable. Even If I don't have LaTeX installed, just opening the TEX file with a simple text editor I can make sense of the phrases, which syllables are stressed and not.

Comment: @ZoltanKing I added your example about Alongerword Word to my example.

Comment: the problem with your example is that it omits the last word, for example `{What kind of books do you like to read}` produces `What kind of books do you like to`

Comment: @ZoltanKing It was my mistake in the `\replspace` macro. I corrected it now.

Answer (score 5):

To get started, put your layout in a macro with two parameters:

`\xitem{<words>}{<phonetic transcription>}`

or for use in normal text the similar

`\transc{<words>}{<phonetic transcription>}`

With `enumerate` or `itemize`

[image: a]

In normal text

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% not needed anymore
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setmainfont{Charis SIL}

\geometry{a4paper, left=1in, right=1in, top=0.5in, bottom=0.65in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.4}

\usepackage{tikz}         

\usepackage{stackengine}
\renewcommand\stacktype{L}

\newcommand{\lstress}[1]
{%
    \addstackgap[10pt]{\stackon{#1}{%
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \fill[opacity=0] circle (0.5ex);
                \fill circle (0.25ex);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }%
    }%
}%

\newcommand{\hstress}[1]
{%
\addstackgap[10pt]{\stackon{\bfseries{#1}}{\tikz \fill circle (0.5ex);}}%
}%

\newcommand{\xitem}[2]{% added <<<<<<<<<<<
    \item #1\par\addvspace{-0.5ex}#2\par\addvspace{3ex}
}

\newcommand{\transc}[2]{%to use in normal text added <<<<<<<<<<<
 #1\par\addvspace{-0.5ex}#2\par\addvspace{3ex}
}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

\begin{enumerate}   
    \item \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word}
    
    \par\addvspace{-0.5ex}{phonetic transcription phonetic transcription phonetic transcription phonetic transcription phonetic transcription phonetic transcription}\par\addvspace{3ex}
    
    \item \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word}
    
    \par\addvspace{-0.5ex}{phonetic transcription phonetic transcription phonetic transcription phonetic transcription phonetic transcription phonetic transcription}\par\addvspace{3ex}
    
    \item \hstress{What} \hstress{kind} \lstress{of} \hstress{books} \lstress{do} \lstress{you} \hstress{like} \lstress{to} \hstress{read}?
    \par\addvspace{-0.5ex}{phonetic transcription}\par\addvspace{3ex}
\end{enumerate}

Using \verb|\xitem|


\begin{enumerate}  
    \xitem{\lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word}}{phonetic transcription phonetic transcription phonetic transcription phonetic transcription phonetic transcription phonetic transcription}

    \xitem{\hstress{What} \hstress{kind} \lstress{of} \hstress{books} \lstress{do} \lstress{you} \hstress{like} \lstress{to} \hstress{read}?}{phonetic transcription}
    
\end{enumerate} 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

\newpage

In a normal text  use the similar \verb|\transc|

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.


\transc{\lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word}}{phonetic transcription phonetic transcription phonetic transcription phonetic transcription phonetic transcription phonetic transcription}

\transc{\lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word} \lstress{Word} \hstress{Word}}{phonetic transcription phonetic transcription phonetic transcription phonetic transcription phonetic transcription phonetic transcription}

\transc{\hstress{What} \hstress{kind} \lstress{of} \hstress{books} \lstress{do} \lstress{you} \hstress{like} \lstress{to} \hstress{read}?}{phonetic transcription}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

\end{document}
```